# Registration-free COM doesn't work when run from a service

Tags: service, com, dllregistration

I'm quite experienced with Registration-Free COM and manifests, but I'm stumped by a problem that I cannot overcome. I have an executable that is run as a windows service, and it spawns another executable (using CreateProcess).  The spawned executable uses a COM library (that we make as well), and has a manifest file that defines the COM assembly.

It should be noted that the windows service can be run as a console mode from a command-prompt as well, for debugging purposes. When I run the service in console mode, the spawned executable "sees" the COM library, so the manifest is working correctly. When it is run as a service, I always get a "Class not registered" error in the spawned process.

I don't know why it's not working. Is it a registration-free limitation? If I register the COM library then all works fine (in console mode or service mode), but I'd obviously like to avoid that.

Thanks,

Normand

Comment: Very vague.  Is the manifest in a file or is it embedded as a resource?  If it is a file then have you at least used Sysinternals' ProcMon to see if where Windows looked for it?

Comment: The manifest is in a file along-side the executable. My next step was to embed the manifest in the exe. I'll take a look at ProcMon but I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: Not vague to me. :)  But then again I'm a deployment guy who makes a living thinking about dependencies and integration concerns.  99% of developers don't understand that services are started in System32 and that always causes a problem when they have some form of relative path dependency which a regfree com manifest would.

Answer (score 1):

Might it be that the current directory of a windows service is the system32 folder?   Try changing the environment once you are running and see if it'll then resolve the manifest file.

Odds are this is the problem but I don't want to spend the hour it would take to mock it all up and test it. :)

Comment: Good idea, I'll check on this asap and I'll let you know of the outcome.

Comment: That was it! Many thanks, and after giving it some thought it makes sense, as the manifest uses relative paths.